# Определение высоты блока и загрузка файла з параметром высоты блока

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Мне нужно на сайте определить высоту блока `<div>`, эту высоту передать в .php файл и загрузить из него текст в опережение место на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var divHeight = $('div').height(); // высота блока
$.ajax({
    url: 'path_to_file/file.php'
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'html',
    data: {blockHeight: divHeight},
    success: function(htmlData){
        $('someBlock').html(htmlData); // htmlData - ваш текст/html, переданные 
                                       // из php-файла
    }
});
```

*В php-обработчике, ловим глобальную переменную $_POST['blockHeight'];